# why do we write create/replace for creating a procedure in PL/SQL

Tags: stored-procedures, syntax, plsql

Can anyone explain why do we write CREATE OR REPLACE for creating a stored procedure in PL/SQL?

Answer (score 4):

OR REPLACE allows you to replace a procedure which already exists, in other words, you dont need to drop the procedure and recreate it each time you want to recreate it

Answer (score 2):

REPLACE KEYWORD Allows you to Modify Data Base Objects Already exist.

consider below examples then you understand clearly.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pr_greetings
IS 
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello');
END;
```

OUTPUT:

```
PROCEDURE PR_GREETINGS compiled
```

If we try to modify without REPLACE KEYWORD we get error,
SO i should drop it and Re-create it.
see below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pr_greetings              ``
IS
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello World');
END;

OUTPUT:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
```

Now with REPLACE KEYWORD we can modify that

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_greetings
IS
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello World');
END;

OUTPUT:
PROCEDURE PR_GREETINGS compiled.
```

I Hope You Understand Clearly,
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1 To modify the procedure without 'create or replace' you have to drop and recreate the object itself in two steps.

2 The main reason is to preserve the object grants:

```
SQL> connect to hr
Connected to Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 
Connected as hr

SQL> 
SQL> create procedure dummy
  2  as
  3  begin
  4      null;
  5  end dummy;
  6  /
Procedure created


SQL> grant execute on dummy to bps;

Grant succeeded

SQL> connect bps
Connected to Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 
Connected as bps

SQL> select * from user_tab_privs_recd where table_name ='DUMMY';

OWNER                          TABLE_NAME                     GRANTOR                        PRIVILEGE                                GRANTABLE HIERARCHY
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ---------------------------------------- --------- ---------
HR                             DUMMY                          HR                             EXECUTE                                  NO        NO
SQL> exec hr.dummy;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> connect hr
Connected to Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 
Connected as hr

SQL> create or replace procedure dummy
  2  as
  3  begin
  4      null;
  5      dbms_output.put_line('dummy');
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created

SQL> select * from user_tab_privs_made where table_name ='DUMMY';

GRANTEE                        TABLE_NAME                     GRANTOR                        PRIVILEGE                                GRANTABLE HIERARCHY
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ---------------------------------------- --------- ---------
BPS                            DUMMY                          HR                             EXECUTE                                  NO        NO

SQL> connect bps
Connected to Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 
Connected as bps

SQL> 
SQL> select * from user_tab_privs_recd where table_name ='DUMMY';

OWNER                          TABLE_NAME                     GRANTOR                        PRIVILEGE                                GRANTABLE HIERARCHY
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ---------------------------------------- --------- ---------
HR                             DUMMY                          HR                             EXECUTE                                  NO        NO


SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec hr.dummy;

dummy

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> connect hr
Connected to Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 
Connected as hr
 SQL> drop procedure dummy;

Procedure dropped
SQL> create  procedure dummy
  2  as
  3  begin
  4      null;
  5      dbms_output.put_line('dummy');
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created
SQL> -- as you can see priviliges previously made are gone
SQL> select * from user_tab_privs_made where table_name ='DUMMY';

GRANTEE                        TABLE_NAME                     GRANTOR                        PRIVILEGE                                GRANTABLE HIERARCHY
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ---------------------------------------- --------- ---------

SQL> connect bps
Connected to Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 
Connected as bps
SQL> select * from user_tab_privs_recd where table_name ='DUMMY';

OWNER                          TABLE_NAME                   GRANTOR                        
------------------------------ ---------------------------------------- 
SQL> exec hr.dummy;

begin hr.dummy; end;

ORA-06550: line 2, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'HR.DUMMY' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

SQL>
```